# scarne's dice game:the comp_overall_score is not getting updated

Tags: java, android

the below code is a part of code where computer plays the game. and the problem is the comp_overall_score is not getting updated when computer plays.
plzz help.

```
 while(comp_turn_score < 20)
    {
        //roll logic
        rollValue = rolldice();
        Log.v("\nComputer Roll:",Integer.toString(rollValue));
        if(rollValue != 1)
        {
            comp_turn_score += rollValue;
            updateLabel("Computer's Turn Score: " + comp_turn_score);

            return;
        }
        else //computer  roll a 1
        {
            //reset turn score to 0 and give control to user
            comp_turn_score = 0;
            updateLabel("\nComputer rolled a 1! Your's Turn");
            rollb.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    //computer holds
    comp_overall_score+= comp_turn_score;
    updateLabel("\nComputer Holds! Your's Turn");
    if(checkWinner()) return;
    rollb.setEnabled(true);

}
private void updateLabel(String s)
{
    lable.setText("\nYour score: " + user_overall_score + " Computer Score: " + comp_overall_score +" " + s);
}
```

Comment: well it looks like it will only update if the value is == 1
the return will stop the function.
I think you were looking for break/continue instead of return

Comment: What is the initial value of `comp_turn_score`? What is the value of variable `rollValue `? You change `comp_turn_score` to `0` from your `else` block. Do not forget that this variable decides your loop condition.

Comment: basically the **rollvalue** is a random number generated between 1 to 6 and and **comp_turn_score** is getting updated every time with respect to **rollvalue**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  if(rollValue != 1)
    {
        comp_turn_score += rollValue;
        updateLabel("Computer's Turn Score: " + comp_turn_score);

        return;
    }
```

Remove the return statement and all would work as planned.